# AsyncStorage returns null [react-native]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, asyncstorage

I have a createSwitchNavigator which has 3 routes with initialRouteName as AuthLoading

App.js

```
import AuthLoadingScreen from './screens/AuthLoadingScreen';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  DrawerItems,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthScreen";
import ProductsScreen from "./screens/ProductsScreen";
import AuthLoadingScreen from "./screens/AuthLoadingScreen";
import ForgetPasswordScreen from "./screens/ForgetPasswordScreen";
import ProductsDemo from "./screens/ProductsDemo";
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/RegisterScreen";

const AppNavigator = () => {
  return <MainNavigation />;
};

const AppBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    home: ProductsScreen
  }
);

const MainNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppBottomTabNavigator,
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: width - width / 4,
    drawerPosition: "left",
    drawerOpenRoute: "DrawerOpen",
    drawerCloseRoute: "DrawerClose",
    drawerToggleRoute: "DrawerToggle",
    drawerBackgroundColor: "#fff",
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);


const AuthDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Products: createStackNavigator(
      {
        SignIn: AuthScreen,
        ForgetPwd: ForgetPasswordScreen,
        SignUp: RegisterScreen,
        Product: ProductsDemo
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "Product",
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
      }
   )
 },
 {
   drawerWidth: width - width / 4,
   drawerPosition: "left"
 }
);

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
    navigatorRef = this.navigator;
  }
  render() {
    const Main = createSwitchNavigator({
      AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: AuthDrawerNavigator,
      App: AppNavigator
    });
    return (
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <Main />
        </PaperProvider>
      </StoreProvider>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

The AuthLoadingScreen just checks...  if app has a token, log user in else route to AuthDrawerNavigator, the AuthDrawerNavigator has a registration and login page.

AuthLoadingScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, StatusBar } from 
"react-native";

class AuthLoadingScreen extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.loadApp()
    }

    loadApp = async () => {
        const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

        this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken? 'App' : 'Auth');
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#fff"
        }}
      >
        <StatusBar translucent={false} backgroundColor="#007aff" />
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#007aff" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default AuthLoadingScreen;
```

In my RegisterScreen, as the user gets registered on backend, im storing his or her details locally using AsyncStorage...

```
const registerUser = async (first_name, last_name, email, pwd_1, phone, dispatch) => {
axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}registerUser`, {
    phone: `+91${phone}`,
    first_name: `${first_name}`,
    last_name: `${last_name}`,
    email: `${email}`,
    pwd: `${pwd_1}`
})
.catch(err => dispatch({
    type: REQ_FAIL,
    val: err.message
}))
dispatch({
    type: REQ_SUCCESS
})
await AsyncStorage.setItem('f_name', first_name);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('l_name', last_name);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('email', email);
await AsyncStorage.setItem('phone', phone);
```

}

Now, as the user is getting registered, im storing their details locally and after registration im routed to loginScreen and after login, im able to see details in homeScreen

ProductsScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  AsyncStorage,
} from "react-native";
import { Appbar } from "react-native-paper";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

class ProductsScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    phone: "",
    email: ""
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    let f_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("f_name");
    let l_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("l_name");
    let phone = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phone");
    let email = await AsyncStorage.getItem("email");
    this.setState({
      first_name: f_name,
      last_name: l_name,
      phone: phone,
      email: email
    });
  }


render() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>

        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 12,
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-around",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginHorizontal: 12,
              marginVertical: 5,
              elevation: 1,
              zIndex: 9
            }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                marginVertical: 8
              }}
              alignSelf="center"
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={require("../components/Images/avatar.png")}
            />
            <View style={{ justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
              <Text>{`${this.state.first_name} ${
                this.state.last_name
              }`}</Text>
              <Text>{this.state.phone}</Text>
              <Text>{this.state.email}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductsScreen;
```

But next time as the user is already registered,user is directly routed to loginScreen and after logging in, this time AsyncStorage is returning null

Though the code for retrieving values from asyncStorage is same as above:

```
  async componentWillMount() {
let f_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("f_name");
let l_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("l_name");
let phone = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phone");
let email = await AsyncStorage.getItem("email");
this.setState({
  first_name: f_name,
  last_name: l_name,
  phone: phone,
  email: email
});
```

}

Comment: Share your code that is extracting the value from AsyncStorage please.

Comment: @SurajMalviya  here is my code fetching values `async componentWillMount() {
    let f_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("f_name");
    let l_name = await AsyncStorage.getItem("l_name");
    let phone = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phone");
    let email = await AsyncStorage.getItem("email");
    this.setState({
      first_name: f_name,
      last_name: l_name,
      phone: phone,
      email: email
    });
  }
`

Comment: Your code doesn't give any wrong hint about saving and retrieving. Can you first ensure if the `setItem` calls are actually executed ?

Comment: How do you know that "AsyncStorage is returning null"? You don't print the values when you retrieve them. Also, `setState` is asynchronous (and the entire `componentWillMount` is as well) so if you check the values somewhere they will be null (or whatever they're set to in the constructor) before `setState` and `componentWillMount` resolves.

Comment: @SurajMalviya  im sure about setItem because, i can see the details properly when im going through registration form but getting null when going from loginScreen

Comment: @JJJ            
i will give a check on these points

Comment: @JJJ    
im getting exact values as i stored them, as i already mentioned that if i enter the app by registering im getting the stored values but whereas if im already registered im routed directly to the login page and from there i cant see the data stored since in return i get null values, please read my question properly

Comment: Well how about you write the question properly? Make a [mcve] that replicates the problem, there's nothing in the code shown in the question that would explain it.

Comment: @JJJ            
i have edited the question and tried to keep it in the format as you mentioned, can you please help me out...
Its not like im not getting the values at all, im getting those values when the user is going via the registrationScreen else if user is going through loginScreen, then details are null

Comment: @SurajMalviya 

is it something like AsyncStorage doesn't work properly without redux-persist, since im getting many links to use redux-persist to keep my data persistent

Comment: @JJJ           
can you also guide me on this, is it something like AsyncStorage doesn't work properly without redux-persist, since im getting many links to use redux-persist to keep my data persistent

Comment: @ManojYadav, `AsyncStorage` has nothing to do with `redux-persist`, `AsyncStorage` is the core class on RN that represents app oriented data which which expose methods that help developers store and retrieve data across app lifecycles, you can think of it as [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) in android. 
However, `redux-persist` is a  library that helps in storing redux store across app lifecycle which gives the possibility to choose its storage as `AsyncStorage`. You don't need to use `redux-persist` to use `AsyncStorage`